# Launching a Ruby Script from the bash does not work, even with the shebang

Tags: bash, ruby

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. I've recently installed the `ruby1.9.1` package and the `wx-ruby gem` using :

```
sudo gem install wxruby-ruby19
```

in order to install the ruby1.9 compatible version.

So I wrote a ruby script called `fenetre_wx.rb` (which has already execution right)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "wx"
include Wx

class FenetrePrincipale < App
    def on_init
            Frame.new(nil, -1, "My app in Ruby with WxRuby", Point.new(-1,-1), Size.new(640,480)).show
    end
end

FenetrePrincipale.new.main_loop
```

No problem when I call

```
 ruby fenetre_wx.rb
```

But when I do :

```
 ./fenetre_wx.rb
```

I get the following error :

> bash: ./fenetre_wx.rb: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Which can be translated by :

> "No file nor directory of this type" :

I've got the French version, but maybe my translation is wrong, so I left the original text.

Does someone know what's wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that the ruby version used in both cases is the same one. `which ruby` vs `env | grep ruby`

Comment: You're right : whereas "which ruby" gave me 'usr/bin/ruby' ; "env | grep ruby" did not give me anything. So how can I correct it ? I've replaced the shabang with /usr/bin/ruby : but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that line endings are unix style in your source file and the source doesn't start with the byte order mark. Byte order mark is a three hex number sequence ( 0xef 0xbb 0xbf) which are invisible through any editor. [refer to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) for a solution to byte order mark problem. and use `dos2unix` for line endings conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much : I first used "sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.rb" then "dos2unix *.rb", and the problem has been solved :) Maybe the problem comes from my Geany editor configuration (though it is in UTF-8)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you program with Windows based tools, find an option that lets you edit unix style, I know that Notepad++ is capable of this. And vim/emacs are available on windows.

Comment: I know what went wrong : I edited the source from a virtual box windows guest, before reusing it in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments,
replace

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: That's done : but I still get the same error .